# why my Action Controller hitting twice in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Form", "Observation", new { area = "" }, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnComplete = "EditAjaxEnd", // standard function name to becalled to end gif loading
    OnBegin = "EditAjaxStart" // standard function name to becalled to call gif loading

}, new { id = "frmAddEdit", @class = "form-horizontal" })) // always name the form for UI block
{
    Html.RenderPartial("FormReporter");
}
```

In FormReporter partial view I have a button

```
<button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-lg blue"
        onclick="return CheckAndSubmit();">Save</button>
```

Everytime I click Save the action controller hitting twice so its saving the record twice.

Is there something that i need to do with partial view?

Comment: What’s happening in the CheckAndSubmit() function? It looks like CheckAndSubmit() submits the form and the Ajax.BeginForm helper does as well.

Comment: CheckAndSubmit()  returns true of false, i dont have submit inside that function

Comment: and even if i replace to    onclick="return true" still hits the controller twice

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the browser, does the request actually send twice?

Comment: tried to change to  onclick="return test()"

    function test() {
        alert("test");
    } 

it only hit once but hits the controller twice.

Comment: You could use the browser debug tool to monitor network request to see how many actual request have been sent to the action

Comment: If you are using chrome check any SRC=" or SRC="#" or any iframes tags or link tags with empty href or # href values.  For some reason I had an issue a while ago with Chrome submitting forms twice because of it.  Changing the # to about:blank fixes the problem.